# Link dataTable With DatagridView

Tags: vb.net

I'm linking `DataTable` with `DatagridView`  but when I want to make new row gives me an error `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code . Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

---

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class DataAssembly_SearchCentral
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim tblresult As DataTable
Dim drCurrent As DataRow
Dim dsdata As New DataSet()

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ResultGV.Rows.Count = 0 Then

        tblresult = New DataTable("tblresult")
        Dim column As DataColumn

        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "Payeer"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.Caption = "Payeer"
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        tblresult.Columns.Add(column)

        column = New DataColumn()
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        column.ColumnName = "Office"
        column.AutoIncrement = False
        column.Caption = "Office"
        column.ReadOnly = False
        column.Unique = False

        tblresult.Columns.Add(column)

        dsdata.Tables.Add(tblresult)

    End If

End Sub
Protected Sub Result_btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles Result_btn.Click

    drCurrent = tblresult.NewRow()
    drCurrent("Payeer") = MasName_txt0.Text
    drCurrent("Office") = ddl_office.SelectedItem.Text
    tblresult.Rows.Add(drCurrent)


    dsdata.Tables.Add(tblresult)
    ResultGV.DataSource = dsdata.Tables("tblresult")

    ResultGV.DataBind()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Which exact line in your code throws the exception?

Comment: in   drCurrent = tblresult.NewRow()    give me the exception

Answer (score 0):

`tblresult` doesn't exist when you try to access it in `Result_btn_Click()`.

Have a look at your `Page_Load()` method:

```
If IsPostBack Then
    Exit Sub ' <-- This gets called and the code below won't execute.
             '     Therefore tblresult doesn't exist in the click handler
End If

If ResultGV.Rows.Count = 0 Then

    tblresult = New DataTable("tblresult")
    ' ...

End If
```

You only create an instance of `tblresult` if it's not a postback. On the other hand whenever the event handler is fired, the request is a postback. Make sure to create an instance of `tblresult` before trying to add a new row.

Comment: Plz give me the Solution , What i can do ?

Comment: Of course the second click gives the same error. `tblresult` only exists when the page is loaded the first time. Every subsequent call to the page won't have the table since it is a postback. I can only give you the hint above. Not knowing any details I won't be able to solve your problem. Please make yourself familiar with how the event model of ASP.NET works. HTTP is a stateless protocol. This has a couple of implications you should be aware of before trying use ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: OK . but What is the ideal Method to Add new row in the dataTable by click event and bind it to datagridview ?

Comment: Any Method To Fill datagridview over steps virtual to save into database one time ?